# how to display remaining time of song in drag mode in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I developed an mp3 player in adobe flash. I want something that when dragging seekbar, time display remains live, like jetaudio windows.

my problem is in line 8

this is my code:

```
function onloops(event:Event):void {

    Object(this).slider_mc.trailer_mc.width=Object(this).slider_mc.knob_mc.x+Object(this).slider_mc.knob_mc.width/2;
    if (soundChannel!=null) {
        pos=soundChannel.position;
        pos3=sound.length-soundChannel.position;
    }
    if (readyToPlay) {
        pos=sound.length*Object(this).slider_mc.knob_mc.x/400;
pos3=(Object(this).slider_mc.knob_mc.x/400)*sound.length;

    }
    if (dragging==true&&soundChannel!=null) {

        pos=sound.length*Object(this).slider_mc.knob_mc.x/400;

        pos3=slider_mc.knob_mc.x/400;


    } else if (soundChannel!=null&&dragging!=true&&readyToPlay==true&&isplaying) {
        pos1=Math.round(soundChannel.position/1000);
        pos2=Math.round(sound.length/1000);
        this.slider_mc.knob_mc.x=Math.round(soundChannel.position/sound.length*400);

    }

    var minutes:Number=Math.floor(pos/1000/60);
    var seconds:Number=Math.floor(pos/1000)%60;
    Object(this).elapsed_totaltime_txt.text=minutes+":"+seconds


    var remainminutes:Number=Math.floor(pos3/1000/60);
    var remainseconds:Number=Math.floor(pos3/1000);
    remainminutes=remainminutes%60;
    remainseconds=remainseconds%60;
    Object(this).remainigtime_txt.text="-"+remainminutes+":"+remainseconds
}
```

Comment: i got it:
pos3=(400-slider_mc.knob_mc.x)/400* sound.length